# Converting Object with nested keys into single object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I want to convert this:

```
data: {
        "3": {
            name: ["Missing data for required field."],
        },
        "5": {
            id: ["Same id exist."],
        },
    }
```

into this:

```
data: [{
        key: "name",
        message: "Missing data for required field.",
        row: 3,
    },
    {
        key: "id",
        message: "Same id exist.",
        row: 5,
    },]
```

how to achieve this with just es6 syntax

Comment: `Object.entries` for a start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `Object.entries`:

```
const data = {
  "3": {
    name: ["Missing data for required field."]
  },
  "5": {
    id: ["Same id exist."]
  }
};

Object.entries(data).map(([a, b]) => {
  return {
    key: Object.keys(b)[0],
    message: Object.values(b)[0][0],
    row: a
  };
});
```

I've made some assumptions:

1. There will only be one key in each object
2. The value of the key will be an array with one string